# Get files and put into list in another method

Tags: python, file, directory

I have a directory with files, I need to get a listing of these files to put into another method. It is in the context of webassets(https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets) so it looks like this, the specific case:

```
app_css = Bundle('app_assets/css/base.css',
                 'app_assets/css/layout.css',,
                 output='output.css',
                 filters='cssmin')
```

and I want to be like this:

```
app_css = Bundle( {any number of files in a directory},
                 output='output.css',
                 filters='cssmin')
```

So I need to retrieve a list of files which might vary and aren't fixed, then put that list into another function, rather than hardcoding each change.

I have this from my last unsuccessful attempt:

```
csspath = "{}/static/css".format(os.path.dirname(__file__))
csss = [["app_assets/css/{}".format(files)] for files in os.listdir(csspath)]
app_css = Bundle("{}".format(*csss), output="packed.css", filters="cssmin")
```

but this isn't right. One of the issues is that I just need the file names, and becasue it is a flask blueprint, need to use the 'app_assets/directory/files' format.

This is basic-python-should-be-easy-101 and a learning experience, and I'll get it, but now that I've turned back to this I'm interested in other solutions, suggestions, etc.

Comment: How does the first bit of code relate to the second?

Comment: The first is a general case, the second is the specific, the third is what I've half done to dynamically format part two.

Comment: In your code it seems like you take the filenames from a directory(the '/static/css' one), and then you want to get the files with those filenames but under a different directory('app_assets/css'). I probably misunderstood your request.

Comment: ok yes, not all that clear originally, perhaps edits are clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a list of all `css` files in a directory you can use the `glob` module:

```
my_files = glob.glob('path_to_the_directory/*.css')
```

Basically `glob` will expand like the filenames in the shell. You can also use it for directories. For example this:

```
glog.glob('My/dir/*/*.css')
```

Would return a list of all filenames that end in ".css" and that are located in a subdirectory of "My/dir".

edit:
A "translation" of your three lines of code:

```
csspath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static', 'css')
csss = [os.path.join('app_assets', 'css', fname) for fname in os.listdir(csspath)]
app_css = Bundle(*csss, output='packed.css', filters='cssmin')
```

But I don't understand if you simply want to improve them or the original version doesn't work.

Comment: I can do that too, my main problem has been formatting the the data between getting the files and the function that requires the data.

Comment: If you don't specify what you want I can't help much. The only thing I can say is that usually it's better to use `os.path` functions to handle paths, because it's simpler and cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

Python Tutorial, §4.7.4, ["Unpacking Argument Lists"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
app_css = Bundle(*['app_assets/css/base.css',
                 'app_assets/css/layout.css'],
                 **dict(output='output.css',
                 filters='cssmin'))
```

Comment: Like I said something really basic I missed or didn't put enough thought into when I first went over it and then moved on.